# Method FloatMath.sqrt() not found

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm using the new Android Marshmallow SDK and the method `FloatMath.sqrt()` is gone. What should I use now?

Answer (score 244, accepted):

The documentations say this:

> Historically these methods were faster than the equivalent double-based
>   java.lang.Math methods. On versions of Android with a JIT they
>   became slower and have since been re-implemented to wrap calls to
>   java.lang.Math. java.lang.Math should be used in preference.
>
> All methods were removed from the public API in version 23.
>
> @deprecated Use java.lang.Math instead.

This means the solution is to use the Math class:

```
(float)Math.sqrt(...)
```

Comment: Ok, but what if it is referenced from a library, and Proguard is complaining?

Comment: I patched that library since I had it as part of my project. However you can implement a wrapper by your own, where you call the existing method.